# What triggers change notification in DependencyProperties?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am exploring databinding in C# and want to understand what kind of changes to a property (backed by a dependency property) actually trigger an update notification to bound targets.

For testing I use a simple setup of classes where I can test changes to nested properties (sub-properties):

```
// Person with a name
public class Person
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
}

// Class giving the best friend as DependencyProperty
public class Friends : DependencyObject
{
    public static DependencyProperty BestFriendProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("BestFriend", typeof(Person), typeof(Friends));

    public Person BestFriend
    {
        get { return (Person)this.GetValue(BestFriendProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(BestFriendProperty, value); }        
    }
}
```

Now I bind the BestFriendProperty (as source) to some Person property of another class. I expected that update notifications via this binding only works if I use the setter of BestFriend:

```
myBoundFriends.BestFriend = new Person(); // myBoundFriends is of type Friends
```

But I discovered that even a direct change of the (nested) Name Property triggers a notification and synchronisation to the bound target works:

```
myBoundFriends.BestFriend.Name = "Otto"; // why does this trigger update?
```

The databinding seems some kind of mysterious to me. Actually I thought that only Freezable objects (used extensively in WPF) are capable of triggering update when any of its sub-properties changes?!

---

Edit: The notification mechanism works as expected when I add a simple Person to Person converter to the binding:

```
public class PersonPersonConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Person p = (Person)value;
        return new Person(String.Copy(p.Name));
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Person p = (Person)value;
        return new Person(String.Copy(p.Name));
    }
}
```

Notice that the converter does a deep copy of the Person object by copying the Name string. I guess this might be a relevant point for the solution.

Comment: The Person.Name property as in your question will not trigger an update of bindings whose sources are Friends.BestFriend. There is something else going on in your code causing the update and which you mistakenly believe is being triggered by assigning "Otto" to the Name property, i guess...

Comment: Yes that is exactly the point. I thought to have understood databinding, but this test case is puzzling me. Do you have a further idea, or a hint how to debug the scenario to find out what is going on?

Comment: You will need to inspect all of your source code which is related to those databindings and/or which can create a Person object (and study under which conditions this happens). If it is too difficult or cumbersome to comb the source code, set a breakpoint in the constructor(s) of *Person* to track who creates Person objects when. If you do not have a constructor declared for *Person*, for the purpose of trouble-shooting implement an empty default constructor on which you can set the breakpoint.

Comment: If you find that your issue is not related to the creation of Person objects, then you need to thoroughly study your source code and program flow -- there are at least as many of different possibilities in what your code could doing as there are different ways to skin a cat...

Comment: @elgonzo: Adding a Person to Person Converter that does a deep copy of the Person object makes the notification mechanism work as expected and the sub-property change does NOT trigger update anymore, but I don't see the point WHY?!

Comment: Frankly and unfortunately, i don't know what your software is doing. All i can say that your software does something -- it might be some sort of strange chain of (side-)effects of several things your software does, and which is somehow be broken up by instantiating a new Person object in the converter. But i honestly don't know. It is not possible to pin-point this 'something' without going through the source code of your software and and analyzing it.

Comment: However, since introducing a converter did something, your problem obviously is not related to the change of the property in code-behind, as you assumed in your question, but it should be an indication that your issue is somewhat related to how you use/setup data bindings...

Comment: I put the whole issue into a minimal test case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25033840/wrong-update-notification-in-c-sharp-databinding-minimal-test-case This should make it easier to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your  problem, your datamodel does not implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

```
public class Person
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

Change it to

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;

    public String Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            if (value == name) return;
            name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator] // Comment out this attribute if you don't have R#
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

This will signal the GUI to redraw anything that's bound to your Name property, when it changes in your code. Alternativly you may use DO as a baseclass and make the Name property a DP, but that's just overkill. I usually have a baseclass that implements the interface for both my viewmodels and datamodels.

And yes I am a resharper addict ;)

Comment: I guess you misunderstood my question. I get change notification in both cases: changing via setter of the bound DP and changing a sub-property of the bound DP. I only expect notification to be triggered in first case, by changing the setter!

Comment: Show your xaml. From your code it looks like you are binding to the Name property on your Person class, which as stated does not have INotifyPropertyChanged or (blah) make Person datamodel a DO with DP's. Witout doing so, your UI will not be signalled when the Name property changes...... You have to do this with all your nested classes! Or be very lazy and make a code clutter by manually calling IE PropertyChanged(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs(String.Empty) which will re evaluate every binding and force a redraw.

Comment: I don't have any XAML code here, this is a minimal non-UI test case.