# Wrong update notification in C# databinding minimal test case

Tags: c#, data-binding, notifications

I have created a minimal test scenario in C# to explore mechanism of databinding. The background is: I wanted to show that changing a sub-property of a property that is bound in databinding does NOT trigger an update to the other side of the binding (Only changing the bound property itself should trigger update)!

BUT I found that it does in my testcase and I am confused wether I have an error in my testcase or databinding actually works that way. The testcase is quite handy:

```
namespace DatabindingMinimal
{
    // Person with a name
    public class Person
    {
        public String Name { get; set; }

        public Person(String name)
        {
            this.Name = name;
        }
    }

    // class exposing a Person as best Friend
    // INotifyPropertyChanged is not implemented here
    public class Friends 
    {
        public Person BestFriend { get; set; }

        public Friends(String bestFriendName)
        {
            this.BestFriend = new Person(bestFriendName);
        }
    }

    // class exposing a Person as father as DependencyProperty
    public class Parents : DependencyObject
    {
        public static DependencyProperty FatherProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Father", typeof(Person), typeof(Parents));

        public Person Father
        {
            get { return (Person)this.GetValue(FatherProperty); }
            set { this.SetValue(FatherProperty, value); }
        }

        public Parents(String fatherName)
        {
            this.Father = new Person(fatherName);
        }
    }

    // test the databinding between Friends and Parents
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Friends f = new Friends("Humphrey");
            Parents p = new Parents("Rudolph");

            Binding bindBeziehungen = new Binding("BestFriend");
            bindBeziehungen.Source = f;
            bindBeziehungen.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(p, Parents.FatherProperty, bindBeziehungen);

            f.BestFriend.Name = String.Empty;   // the p.Father.Name is now set Empty as well

            System.Console.WriteLine(f.BestFriend.Name);
            System.Console.WriteLine(p.Father.Name);

            // ... Both Strings are empty in output now!

            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(f.BestFriend, p.Father))
                System.Console.WriteLine("identical");    // this is true here!
        }
    }
}
```

The testcase binds the friends class as source to an instance of the parents class as target. The friends class does NOT have any notification mechanism! But changing the f.BestFriend.Name property DOES CHANGE the p.Father.Name property! Changing the bound BestFriend property itself does not update anything (as expected):

```
f.BestFriend = new Person("");    // p.Father does not change here!
```

Also the references are not equal at the end when changing f.BestFriend directly!

**Question:**
So, is it normal that references of bound properties are equal after creating the binding and doing an update at one side?

Why does changing f.BestFriend.Name trigger an update at all, even without INotifyPropertyChanged implemented?

I have the feeling that the binding assigns one reference of a bound Person property to match the other behind the scenes?! Can someone clear this issue?

Comment: Additionally to my answer here, i just want to comment regarding the effect of the converter (from your other question, thus not part of my answer here). Note that you created another Person object in the converter. A binding using that converter is of course not equivalent to `p.Father = f.BestFriend;`, but rather equivalent to `p.Father = new Person(something)`. Using that converter, *p.Father* would not refer to the same Person object as *f.BestFriend*, but would refer to **another** Person object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are ask about is not a problem, but rather a result of some confusion or  misunderstanding, i guess.

Look at your data binding. The most important thing this binding does is setting *p.Father* to the same value as *f.BestFriend*. Think of it being equivalent to the following code:

```
p.Father = f.BestFriend;
```

(Okay, the binding is not exactly equivalent with this code with regard to how the binding and the DependencyProperty are maintained. But within the context of this question this is a good-enough simplification.)

What is the result of this? After the binding is initialized, *p.Father* and *f.BestFriend* will refer to the **same** Person object.

You can actually replace the binding in your code with the code line above and experience the very same effect.

There is no magic update (or magic update notification) if you set the **Name** property to another value like:

```
f.BestFriend.Name = String.Empty;
```

Of course you will see the same value for *f.BestFriend.Name* and for *p.Father.Name*, because both *f.BestFriend* and *p.Father* refer to the **very same single Person object** -- which by the way you already found out with the last *if* statement in your code.

There is no magic update of properties from one Person object to another Person object, because, again,  your code deals only with **one single Person object** (and not with two, as you seem to assume).

Regarding

```
f.BestFriend = new Person("");    // p.Father does not change here!
```

of course *p.Father* does not change, and you already know why. Although *f.BestFriend* is the source of the binding, the binding will not know if/when the value of *f.BestFriend* (the value being a reference to a Person object) changes, since it is not being notified due to the lack of a *INotifyPropertyChanged* implementation. Since the binding is not notified, it won't update the value of *p.Father*. After executing this line of code, *f.BestFriend* will refer to a **different** Person object than *p.Father*.

Essentially, all what you wonder about and what you ask about just sprung from a misunderstanding. There are no two Person objects, and there is no binding doing an update (except as part of its initial setup), and there is no property change notification happening at all...

Comment: I see the point. Can a binding always be considered being equal to just assign the one property to the other? So far I thought databinding keeps source and target untouched as two seperate storings in memory and just notifies each other of changes and gives the mechanism to get the updated value. But that doesn't seem to be right, does it?

Comment: No. It is a simplification i made to explain what's going on regarding your situation. The example of using a converter is one example where a binding is not equivalent to an assignment. Also, DependencyProperties could have callbacks which coerce their value (which again would perhaps not result in a simple value assignment). Bindings could be two-way, which would not be like a simple assignment (unless you imagine a two-way assignment :))

Comment: Finally, in your example code, after setting the binding check the value of *p.Father* -- it will refer to the same object as *f.BestFriend*. Then, programmatically, remove the binding again (BindingOperations.ClearBinding(...)), and check *p.Father* again. You will notice, that p.Father will revert to the value (null) it had before you set the binding - so it is actually false to claim that a binding is the *same* as an assignment. It was just a simplification for the sake of keeping my answer brief and relevant to your issue...

Comment: Yes, p.Father results to null after removing the binding, I checked that yesterday for my own confusion :) Thx for your explanations, this issue is very important to me understanding the databinding mechanism.

Comment: Okay. Perhaps think about bindings just updating **values** between the binding source and the binding target (which is true). If you have properties which refer to objects, then the **value** of such properties is a **reference to an object** -- also commonly called a "reference value" (or **null**). Hence, in your code above, the binding copies the value of *f.BestFriend* (an object **reference**) to *p.Father* -- which then contains the same object reference and thus refers/points to the same object as *f.BestFriend*.

Comment: Well, perhaps another goodie regarding bindings not being the same as simple assignments... (yup, i am chatty today ;) ) A converter used in a binding could return *Binding.DoNothing* as THE conversion result, in which case the Binding would not do an update of the respective target property. This would result in a situation where the source property changes while the target property remains unchanged...